# Problem setting up PPTPD

Tags: networking, android, vpn, pptpd

I'm attempting to set up a VPN from my Android phone to my home computer using pptpd on Ubuntu 12.10. I have so far done the following.

Setup a virtual NIC like this...

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and then configured pptpd like this... (commented line has been omitted to save space)

```
cat /etc/pptpd.conf
option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options
debug
logwtmp
localip 192.168.0.1
remoteip 192.168.0.100-200

/etc/ppp/pptpd-options
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
debug
lock
nobsdcomp

/etc/ppp/chap-secrets
andreas         *       a5okg4b99               *
```

But all I get from syslog even with debug turned on is..

```
Apr  8 14:53:25 Ellit pptpd[19488]: MGR: connections limit (100) reached, extra IP addresses ignored
Apr  8 14:53:25 Ellit pptpd[19489]: MGR: Manager process started
Apr  8 14:53:25 Ellit pptpd[19489]: MGR: Maximum of 100 connections available
```

and when I finaly try to connect with my phone all it says is...

```
Apr  8 14:29:43 Ellit pptpd[25180]: MGR: dropped small initial connection
```

I don't realy know where to go from here... have I made and error in thinking that a virtual NIC will work and why can't I get any debug information even when I asked for it in the configurations?

EDIT: The last line when I try to connect seems to appear somewhat random, I can right now not reproduce it but I fairly sure it related to my connection attempt before and I have not changed anything from then. I'm starting to suspect that my Android ISP is blocking VPN but that would be... insane.

Comment: We would need more information on your network topology to start attempting a resolution. Are you attempting to VPN in from a LAN connection or outside your LAN? If from the outside, do you have a public IP address or resolvable hostname? Are the the VPN ports open on your router? Is your machine running a DHCP server, which is required for VPN connections to work?

Comment: Sorry for my very late replay here and thank you for yours. First of all, I needed the VPN because my phone ISP blocked VOIP but without any announcement they stopped doing that... whoho. =) However, there is no firewalls or routers and both sides uses public IP's and the server has a working DNS name. That to say, I can look up the IP from the DNS name but probably not the other way around, was that necessary?

Comment: did you ever get it to work?

Comment: It's 2024. WireGuard is so fast and easy to set up now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Basically, I found that commenting out `require-mppe-128`(`#require-mppe-128`) allows Android based devices to consistently connect to a PPTP based server.

That will however leave your connection unencrypted.